# Ubuntu 22.04 on Oracle Virtualbox - closes window by mouse click after activate

Tags: virtualbox, windows

Host; Windows 10
VM: 7.0.8
Ubuntu: 22.04.2 LTS + Guest Addons
Host key combination: left windows
Mouse integration: on

All works correctly. I press left windows key (do return focus to host) and Alt-tab to change active window. Then mouse cursor in VM changes to black cross and when I left click then active window from VM is closed. I have to first right click to disable to cross mouse cursor.

[image]

This doesn't occur when host key is something different.

Comment: This sounds like more of a Windows issue than one related to Ubuntu. Are there any items in `/var/log/syslog` that points to it being an issue with Ubuntu? 

Comment: I have other VMs on another systems and no such a behavior.